# Date field not giving value in correct format

Tags: java, jdbi

In `List<Map<String, Object>>` values, I am taking values from database. Database side i ahve used defaultMapper to map values. Now when I am fetching the values, only one Date type of field is not giving correct result in values above.
Date is coming in this format in json:  "update_date": 1319529055000

Can anyone tell me how to get this date field mapped correctly using defaultMapper?

Comment: You would first have to define what defaultMapper is. We don't know aything about the architecture and code of your application.

Comment: The defaultmapper is of jdbi. I am taking the values in query having different values like name, id and date. This defaultmapper automatically maps the values in List<Map<String, Object>> values. The values has all the values in correct format except for date type field like:"id": 9321419,
       "name": "test",
       "update_date": 1319529087000                                                         This date should have been in proper format like 18-Nov-13

Comment: Don't you think it might be worth mentioning that you're using JDBI? And tagging your question with jdbi? We can't guess that.

Answer (score 0):

1319529055000 looks like a timestamp, so when you do..

```
Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf("1319529055000"));
System.out.println(d);
```

This will print out `2011-10-25`.  This means you can just use the standard Date object from the JDK to parse this timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Class `Date` [has constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28%29) `Date(long date)`. Use it:

```
Date myDate= new Date(Long.parseLong("1319529055000"));
System.out.println(myDate);
```